# Not able to get TextMeshPro text to variable slot in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
using TMPro;

public TextMeshPro _livesText;
public TextMeshPro _scoreText;
```

I am unable to drag the text from the Hierarchy to the variable slot in Inspector. Why is it happening. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to drag something from the Scene to a prefab in the Assets? -> It is not allowed ;)

Comment: @derHugo No I am not. All I am doing is trying to drag the TMP text from the hierarchy to the slot in the inspector. And it is not accepting it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to speak about a `TextMeshProUGUI` which in the Inspector is called `TextMeshPro - Text(UI)`.

Note that [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.0/api/TMPro.TextMeshPro.html) != [`TextMeshProUGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.0/api/TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI.html)!

There is no inheritance between those two. (Similar to Unity build in `TextMesh` and `UI.Text`)

If you want one general field for both types then you need to use the common parent type [`TMP_Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.0/api/TMPro.TMP_Text.html)

So either make it

```
public TextMeshProUGUI _livesText;
public TextMeshProUGUI _scoreText;
```

or go for the parent class

```
public TMP_Text _livesText;
public TMP_Text _scoreText;
```

---

If this still isn't your case then you seem to be trying to assign a reference from a Hierarchy object in the scene via the Inspector to a prefab in the assets. This is not allowed. Only the other way round.